# React Router with nested children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Looking at the [huge-apps](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples/huge-apps) example on the react-router github, I am not sure how to setup the routes I want.

```
URL        | Result
--------------------------
/sites     | List of sites
/sites/:id | One site
```

If I want to list multiple sites, the Site component/route would need to be nested in the Sites component/route. Therefore, my folder structure would look similar to the Assignments model in the react-router example.

```
/routes
    /Sites
        /components
        |   Sites.js
        /routes
        |   /Site
        |   |   /components
        |   |   |   Site.js
        |   |   index.js
        index.js
```

However, for the `/sites/:id` route, it is not dependent on the Sites component. Would I create another Site directory on the same level at the Sites directory, or would I make the Site component be able to render a list and singular view? What would my index.js files look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would visualize your route tree this way:

```
/sites
(Sites.js)
- /:id1
  (Site1.js)
- /:id2
  (Site2.js)
```

Inside your index.js, something like this (using a client-side example):

```
render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />
      <Route path="/sites" component={Sites}>
        <Route path="/sites/:id" component={Site}/>
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

Each route has an accompanying component. You can throw anything you want in those components, although it probably would be helpful to include some way to navigate to child routes.

PlainRoute version (though I'm not sure why you'd want to):

```
const rootRoute = {
  component: 'div',
  childRoutes: [{
    path: '/',
    component: require('./components/App'),
    childRoutes: [ require('./routes/Sites') ]
  }]
}

render(
  <Router history={browserHistory} routes={rootRoute} />,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

'./routes/Sites':

```
module.exports = {
  path: 'sites',
  getChildRoutes(location, cb) {
    require.ensure([], (require) => cb(null, [ require('./routes/Site') ]))
  },
  getComponent(nextState, cb) {
    require.ensure([], (require) => cb(null, require('./components/Sites')))
  }
}
```

'./routes/Site':

```
module.exports = {
  path: 'sites/:id',
  getComponent(nextState, cb) {
    require.ensure([], (require) => cb(null, require('./components/Site')))
  }
}
```

Comment: How would you do this with PlainRoutes, how the example does?

Comment: I don't know why you'd want to use PlainRoutes when JSX is way more efficient, in terms of readability. I'll append to my original answer my best attempt at a PlainRoutes version, according to the file structure used in the example.

Comment: As you can see [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/examples/huge-apps/app.js), it's better for code splitting. Anyway, thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. One last question, for the JSX routes you put a backslash in front of the paths, but not for the Plain Routes. Does the backslash get appended from the parent route? If so, should `sites/:id` be changed to just `:id`?

Comment: You may well be right. I would need to do some testing to verify; I cannot currently do so. I have always myself written paths as absolute in my JSX routes, in which case, there should be a / in front of every path.

Comment: It could be that sites/:id may need to be a sibling of sites in the root app.

Comment: Looking at the huge-apps example again, specifically the Courses, Assignment, and Assignments nested; I think it would need to be just `:id` for the child route. However, I'm assuming that leading with a backslash for both Site routes would work. My guess is that they didn't use absolute paths in the example to show you can rely on folder structure, which I'm not a fan of.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve, you could do something like this inside your router:

```
<Route path="/sites/:id" component={SingleSite} />
<Route path="/sites" component={Sites} />
```

Where the `SingleSite` component takes the id param and uses it to display the site. React router should be able to use the `SingleSite` component if there is an ID and show the `Sites` component if not.

Comment: Could you just pass a prop to the Site component by the Sites component when it maps/creates each Site?

Comment: I guess that depends on whether you want the `Site` component to display as a child of the `Sites` component or not. I think that because you wouldn't want to show both the list and the individual site at the same time, it would be better to make them siblings under a parent that has an object with all the sites. `Sites` would iterate through that object and display everything and `Site` would receive the `:id` in the params prop of react router, then filter a prop passed down from the parent.

Comment: that makes sense. I guess having both in one component makes it more like a Model in MVC than a component. Is it necessary to put the deeper path first? For example, would putting `/sites/:id` after the `/sites` route cause `/sites/:id` to never be rendered?